# i have 3 text boxes for Day , Month and Year .From this need to calculate a date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 3 textboxes for Day, Month and Year. From this need to calculate a date. And need subtraction functionality also ( Calculation on Current date)

> Eg: Current date = 20-02-2020 , Day -1 and Month - 1 and Year = 1 then the result = 21-03-2021

Comment: Add what you have tried

Comment: `DateTime result = DateTime.Today.AddDay(days).AddMonths(months).AddYears(years);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you all for your time .. 
I have solved my question and sharing for your reference

```
        int value_days = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Days.Text, out value_days);
        int value_months = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Months.Text, out value_months);
        int value_years = 0;
        int.TryParse(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Years.Text, out value_years);
        if ((value_days <= 0 || Convert.ToString(value_days) == "") && (value_months <= 0 || Convert.ToString(value_months) == "") && (value_years <= 0 || Convert.ToString(value_years) == ""))
        {
            dtpRecommendationfor_OP.Value = DateTime.Now;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int OPReview_Days = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Days.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0.ToString() : txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Days.Text.Trim());
            int OPReview_Months = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Months.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0.ToString() : txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Months.Text.Trim());
            int OPReview_years = Convert.ToInt32(txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Years.Text.Trim() == "" ? 0.ToString() : txtRecommendationfor_OPReview_Years.Text.Trim());

            var _date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(OPReview_Days).AddMonths(OPReview_Months).AddYears(OPReview_years);
            dtpRecommendationfor_OP.Value = _date;
        }
```

Comment: (1) You are using TryParse (great) but are ignoring its return value. An invalid text will make the out variable 0 (which in this case might be useful). (2) When you Convert.ToString an int, it will never be an empty string. (3) In the else-part, you are re-parsing the values that you have already collected. (4) You said you also needed subtract capability, this code doesn't have it

Comment: Subtraction is not in this code but it is calling after editing Day/Month/Year so it is recalculating again

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to `Parse` `Text` of the `TextBox`es and `Add` these values to `DateTime.Today`

```
if (int.TryParse(DayTextBox.Text, out int day) &&
    int.TryParse(MonthTextBox.Text, out int months) &&
    int.TryParse(YearTextBox.Text, out int years)) {
  DateTime result = DateTime.Today
    .AddDays(days)
    .AddMonths(months)
    .AddYears(years);

  //TODO: put relevant code here
}
else {
  //  Some of the text boxes has invalid value 
}
```

Please, note that *order* (`.AddDays` then `.AddMonths` or `.AddMonths` then `.AddDays`) *matters*:

```
30 Jan 2020 + 1 Day + 1 Month == 29 Feb 2020
30 Jan 2020 + 1 Month + 1 Day ==  1 Mar 2020
```

Comment: I have a doubt , user can increase or decrease the values in textbox , can we do add and subtract in same logic ?

Comment: @Agnes: if value is *negative* its absolute value will be subtracted: `new DateTime(2020, 2, 20).AddDays(-1) == 2020-02-19`

Comment: values is positive integers , if first user inputting 10 days and same can reduce to 5 e:g: current date 20-02-2020 in case of 10 value will be 01-03-2020 and user reduced textbox value to 5 then date will change to 25-02-2020 this is my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Using `AddDays` and `AddMonths`.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterday = now.AddDays( -1 );
DateTime aMonthBefore = now.AddMonths( -1 );
```

According to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=netframework-4.8), AddMonths will handle leap year.
If you just want to subtract 30 days, use subtract.

```
DateTime thirtyDaysBefore = now.Subtract( new TimeSpan( 30, 0, 0 ) );
```

Comment: The problem with TimeSpan in this case is that it doesn't know about Years or Months, as their length varies

Comment: Yes, so I mention it specifically for "30 days". It still handles leap years but limited to day operation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to only substract or add too? What is the format of your text boxes?

There are several ways of doing this, depending on your input. One example:

```
var yourDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(TextBox1).AddMonths(TextBox2).AddYears(TextBox3);
```

Or you can substract two `DateTimes` from each other.

Comment: i need add and subtract from same text boxes , Format is Integer , and how to check if its add or subtract ?

Comment: You can insert "-1" or "1" into the `Add` methods. If you insert -1, it will subtract, if it's 1, it will add. @Agnes

Comment: but input will always positive integers

Comment: `TextBox1` is just the control. You need to use its `.Text` property and convert that string to integer

Comment: @Agnes And how do you distinguish between subtraction and addition if the numbers are always positive?

Comment: @Agnes If you want only subtraction, you can add `-` to every command (like `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-TextBox1.Text);`

Comment: that is my challenge . i need to do both from same text box